# Archlinux downgrade gcc from 5.2 to 4.8

Tags: gcc, archlinux

I want to downgrade my gcc on the current ArchLinux.

```
    Makefile:545: recipe for target 'libstdc++.la' failed
    make[6]: *** [libstdc++.la] Error 139
    make[6]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-        build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src'
    Makefile:575: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[5]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-        build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src'
    Makefile:480: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[4]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-        build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
    Makefile:386: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-        build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
    Makefile:12181: recipe for target 'all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
    make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-build'
    Makefile:19114: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
    make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/yaourt-tmp-jester/aur-gcc48/src/gcc-build'
    Makefile:885: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    ==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
        Aborting...
    ==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build gcc48.
    ==> Restart building gcc48 ? [y/N]
    ==> ------------------------------
    ==>
```

When I am trying to install the gcc via 
        yaourt --noconfirm --needed gcc48

Does anybody know why it is not working. The errors does not help me anyways...

Comment: Please do not add an answer via an edit. Instead, post a new answer.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on arch linux it is fine to use the shell command:

> downgrade gcc

Comment: yes, it works. https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Using_Downgrade

Comment: Also, downgrading gcc-libs too could be required:
```downgrade gcc gcc-libs```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
pacman -U <file_name_of_the_package>
```

Of course, you must have the version you want over there.

```
-> alexmina
"downgrade gcc"
```

Are you sure what you are using is Archlinux?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify both `gcc` and `gcc-libs`. For example, if you want to downgrade from `7.1.1` to `6.3.1`:

Method 1)

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-6.3.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-libs-6.3.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Method 2)

```
downgrade gcc gcc-libs
```

And select wanted versions.